# Unwanted page reloading sqlite3 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite, web

I'm currently making a game list for collection and i use database. I decided to use SQlite3 to communicate with database.

The problem is when I do a fecth to add or remove a game to the collection by clicking a button, it's running a INSERT code or DELETE code and then it's reloading my page.

I already tried to use event.preventDefault() but it doesn't cancel the relaoding

Do you know why?

Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="game-footer">
    <div class="button-add-rem">
        <button wii-game-button></button>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- The button is not on a FORM -->
```

```
// This is the event Listener
gameButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/ajoutsuppr?gameID=${gameID}`)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.result === false){
                console.log("Was not on list, added")
            } else {
                console.log("Was on list, deleted")
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error when request :', error);
    });
});
```

```
app.get('/ajoutsuppr', (req, res) => {
    const gameID = req.query.gameID; // Recover game ID
    db.get(`SELECT * FROM gamelist WHERE id = ?`, [gameID], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error :', err.message);
        } else {
            if (row) {
                // This part make the page reloading
                db.run(`DELETE FROM gamelist WHERE id = ?`, [gameID], (err) => {
                    if (err) return console.error("Erro during inserting id to database: ", err.message);
                });
                res.json({result: true}) //If game was in the list, then delete
            } else {
                // This part make the page reloading
                db.run(`INSERT INTO gamelist VALUES (?,?)`, [gameID, Date.now()], (err) => {
                    if (err) return console.error("Error during inserting id to database: ", err.message);
                }); //else, i add it
                res.json({result: false})
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I expect just to not have the page reloading everytime i use `db.run` function when clicking a button

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault() to cancel events.

Comment: Already tried but it doesn't cancel the reloading, i put it before, after the fetch and on the fetch but don't work.